# CHM file from XSD files

Tags: xsd, sandcastle

Is it possible to create a CHM file or HTML help (akin to those created by Sandcastle) from an XSD file? Text in the `xs:documentation` nodes contains, well, the documentation.

An example snippet from one of the XSD files I have is

```
<xs:element name="Request" type="RequestType">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            <html:p>The Request message contains a number of <html:i>RequestType</html:i> elements for the server to process.</html:p>
            <html:p>A <html:i>Request</html:i> will always result in a <html:i>Response</html:i> message being returned by the server, and <html:b>must</html:b> contain an <html:b>xmlns=[<html:i>Default namespace</html:i>]</html:b> declaration.</html:p>
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Response" type="ResponseType">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>The Response message contains the result of a previous <html:i>Request</html:i> message, with one <html:i>ResponseType</html:i> element for each <html:i>RequestType</html:i> sent to the server.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 3):

[XML Schema Documenter](https://github.com/terrajobst/xsddoc) is a [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/releases) plug-in that allows you to integrate reference documentation for XML schemas in your help files.

Answer (score 1):

There's a XSLT called "xs3p" which can be downloaded from [xml.fiforms.org/xs3p](http://xml.fiforms.org/xs3p/).

You can use any XSLT processor to convert your XSD into HTML - I use "[nxslt3](http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000722.html)" by Oleg Tkachenko.

A second step would then be to combine several HTML into a CHM using some Html Help builder.

Marc

PS: forgot to mention - both tools are free, of course :-)